# Error while iterating over a matrix in eigen

Tags: c++, matrix, stl, iteration, eigen

I am trying to iterate over a 2D matrix in eigen
"

```
ArrayXXi A = ArrayXXi::Random(4,4).abs();
   for(auto row : A.rowwise())
   std::sort(row.begin(), row.end());
```

"

I am trying to implement this example but it doesn't seem to work.
I am receiving the following error
"Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::end(_Container &)"
I am using visual studio 2019.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using the master branch of Eigen? Iterators are not part of Eigen 3.3.x

Comment: Then how do you assign values to these matrices. We can't just go on typing each value. This code snippet I have taken from Eigen website itself.  https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSTL.html.

Comment: Which version of Eigen are you using?

Comment: I am using current version 3.3.7